# Initialization of Arcs depening on Sets/Subsets in directed graphs in CPLEX

Tags: graph, set, cplex, directed-graph

I am dealing with a directed weighted graph and have a question about how to initialize a set a defined in the following:

Assume that the graph has the following nodes, which are subdivided into three different subsets.

```
//Subsets of Nodes
{int} Subset1= {44,99};
{int} Subset2={123456,123457,123458};
{int} Subset3={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
{int} Nodes=Subset1 union Subset2 union Subset3;
```

Now there is a set of H_j arcs, where j is in Nodes. H_j gives all arcs outgoing from Node j.
The arcs are stored in an excel file with the following structure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Bd8.png)

For node 44 in Nodes (Subset 1), there are the arcs <44,123456>, <44,123457>, <44,123458>. For 66 in Nodes (Subset 2), there is no arc. Can somebody help me how to implement this?
Important is that the code uses the input from the excel because in my real case there will be too much data to make a manual input... :(

Maybe there is a real easy solution for that. I would be very thankful!
Thank you so much in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Bd8.png)

**This addition refers to the answer from @Alex Fleischer:**
Your code seems to work also in the overall context.
I am trying to implement the following constraints within a Maximization optimization ( The formulations (j,99) and (j,i) in the lower sum boundaries represent arcs):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lYtr.png)

I tried to implement it like this:

```
{int} TEST= {99};
subject to {
    sum(m in M, j in a[m])x[<44,j>]==3;
    sum(j in destPerOrig[99], t in TEST)x[<j,t>]==3;
    forall(i in Nodes_wo_Subset1)
    sum(j in destPerOrig[i],i in destPerOrig[i])x[<j,i>]==1;
}
```

M is a set of trains and a[M] gives a specific cost value for each indiviudal train. CPLEX shows 33 failure messages.
The most frequent one is that it cannot extract x[<j,i>], sum(in in destPerOrig[i]), sum(j in destPerOrig[i] and that x and destPerOrig are outside of the valid area.

Most probably the problem is that I implement the constraints in the wrong manner. Again, it is a directed graph.

Referring to the mathematical formulation in the screenshot: Could the format of destPerOrig[i] be a problem?
At the moment destPerOrig[44] gives {2 3 4}. But should´t it give:
{<44 2> <44 3> <44 4>} to work within the mathematical formulation?

I hope that this is enoug information for you to help me :(

I would be very thankful!

Comment: I think that was a missunderstanding due to unperfect formulation. H_j is not in Nodes. As you say: H_j is a set of arcs. What i ment: j is in Nodes. I will reformulate it above.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

> all arcs outgoing from Node j.

How to do this depends on how you store the adjacencies of the graph.

Perhaps you store a vector of arcs:

```
LOOP over arcs
   IF arc source == node J
       ADD to output
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @ravensoint ! To be honest I tried to apply your recommend but did not really understand how to do it. I posted the problem in better order and with better explanation in a new thread today. I would be very thankful if you could have a look at it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189878/variable-set-of-arcs-in-lower-bound-of-the-sum-of-a-constraint-directed-graph-cp

Answer (score 0):

.mod

```
tuple arcE
{
 string o;
 string d;
}

{arcE} arcsInExcel=...;

{int} orig={ intValue(a.o) | a in arcsInExcel};

{int} destPerOrig[o in orig]={intValue(a.d) | a in arcsInExcel : intValue(a.o)==o && a.d!="" };

execute
{
  writeln(orig);
  writeln("==>");
  writeln(destPerOrig);
}

/*
which gives

 {44 66}
==>
 [{2 3 4} {}]
*/
```

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readarcs.mod

.dat

```
SheetConnection s("readarcs.xlsx");

arcsInExcel from SheetRead(s,"A2:B5");
```

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readarcs.dat

Comment: Thank you very much again for this quick and helpful answer! At the first glance, it seems to solve my problem. I will test it in the overall context of my problem and see if that´s it :)

Comment: Hey, I tried to implement my objective function and the corresponding constraints for my directed graph. Actually it failed and I don´t know why. I decribed it above as precisly as possible. Maybe you know a solution?

Comment: I think my question above has become a bit messy due to adding further information again and again. So I made a new thread with better order and explanation. Maybe the solution you already provided fits perfect but I just implemented it in the wrong manner!